# Create new API fields for CS-Cart Users

Tags: cs-cart

Is there a way i can create custom fields for **Users** in CS-Cart where i can store a particular value unique to each user using the CS-Cart API?

I want to add two unique fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users API is cs-cart built-in Entity.  You can find Users entity (php code) from this folder `/app/Tygh/Api/Entities/Users.php` 
you can edit the Users.php for your desired purpose.